# How can I stop a repeating function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a toggle function in my code that when clicked, a ul block shows and when clicked again, the ul block disappears. I am using this in conjunction with a WordPress plugin called search and filter pro.

When I select one of the filters, some AJAX from the plugin runs so I have to declare what I want the code to do after the AJAX is finished running and so I put in my function again.

**Original function**

```
function pageFunctions() {
    // CHECKING ON AVAILABILITY OF VANS
    
    let singleVan = document.querySelector('.single-vans')
    let numberFilters = document.querySelector('.number-of-filters p')
    let count = 0;
    
    let availability = document.querySelectorAll('.availability')
    let content = document.querySelectorAll('.vans')
    
    // HIDING AND SHOWING FILTER OPTIONS
    let filter = document.querySelectorAll('.searchandfilter ul li h4')
    let filterBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.searchandfilter li ul')
    let filterLi = document.querySelectorAll('[data-sf-meta-type="choice"]')

    filter.forEach( (tag, index) => {
        tag.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
           console.log('clicked')
           filterLi[index].classList.toggle('active')
           if (!filterLiOpen[index]) {
           filterLiOpen[index] = true;
           }
           else if (filterLiOpen[index]) {
            filterLiOpen[index] = false;
           }
           console.log(filterLiOpen)
        })
    })
}
```

**What happens after AJAX**

```
(function ( $ ) {
  "use strict";
  $(document).on("sf:ajaxfinish", ".searchandfilter", function(){
        pageFunctions();
  });
}(jQuery));
```

I am assuming that both functions are running and so they cancel each other out with the toggle but I am not certain. How can I go about preventing this from occurring?

It's worth noting that it works perfectly fine until I scroll down to refresh more results, after that, the toggle stops working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

live example: https://snapstaging.co.uk/coolkitnew/vans/

Comment: "...works perfectly fine until I scroll down..." Did you post a question with that (IMHO, bigger) problem along with scroll code, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you are adding new click handlers every time an AJAX call completes.

The initial set of click handlers are added when the page loads, and it "works".

Then you load new data over AJAX and you add another round of ADDITIONAL click handlers, so when a user clicks to expand a filter the first handler is invoked and then the second handler is immediately invoked, undoing it.

If you then load AJAX data one more time, this will add ANOTHER set of handlers "fixing" the issue (until you load data for a fourth time).

Solution: add the click handlers once on page load; then merely toggle filter visibility when needed (eg when AJAX completes) instead of adding additional handlers.